# AutoMapper ignore parent properties of complex types

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using AutoMapper 6.2.2 and I have a generic method which performs object graph updating from one type to another. I don't know all the combinations at runtime therefor the mapper is wrapped in an extension method which uses `T` for the `CreateMap` type parameters.

The configuration I have accomplishes my requirements, however the problem is, `Foo.MyBar` is updated instead of descending and comparing its child properties. I only expect `Foo.MyBar` to be completely overwritten if its null. As I cannot make a configuration specifically for `Foo.MyBar`, how can I write a generic conditional in my configuration to accomplish my needs?

I am expecting `result.MyBar.TwoString` = "yyy", not "world".

```
public class Bar
{
    public string OneString { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string TwoString { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Bar MyBar { get; set; }

    public int? MyNumber { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string MyString { get; set; }

    public string[] MyStringArray { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Foo model = new Foo
        {
            MyString = "aaa",
            MyNumber = 42,
            MyBar = new Bar { OneString = "xxx", TwoString = "yyy" }
        };

        Foo update = new Foo
        {
            MyString = "bbb",
            MyNumber = 77,
            MyBar = new Bar { OneString = "hello", TwoString = "world" }
        };

        MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
            cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
            cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Foo>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Foo>().ForAllMembers(opt =>
                opt.Condition((source, destination, sourceMember, destMember) =>
                    (sourceMember != null)));
            cfg.ForAllPropertyMaps(map =>
                    map.SourceMember.GetCustomAttribute<ReadOnlyAttribute>()?.IsReadOnly == true,
                (map, configuration) =>
                {
                    configuration.Ignore();
                });
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        Foo result = mapper.Map(update, model);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried with adding mapping for Bar as well, like `cfg.CreateMap<Bar, Bar>();`

Comment: Yes, that produces the correct result but I wont know all the types at runtime. The mapper configuration and instantiation is encapsulated in a generic method, all I know is the root graph type. According to https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/656, is there a way to swap default assignable mapper out?